# Java Selenium org/openqa/selenium/Capabilities

Tags: java, selenium, ant

I have problem with selenium and ant. when I build my project, build is successfull, but when I want to run jar file its failed.

error is:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Capabilities
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
```

what I have to add to lib folder or to build.xml?

My build.xml:

```
<project>
<property name="app.name" value="Downloader"/>
<property name="dir.src" value="src"/>
<property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>
<property name="build.dir" value="build"/>

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>



<pathconvert property="mf.classpath" pathsep=" ">
    <path refid="classpath"/>
    <mapper>
        <chainedmapper>
            <flattenmapper/>
            <globmapper from="*.jar" to="${lib.dir}/*.jar"/>
        </chainedmapper>
    </mapper>
</pathconvert>

<mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
<javac srcdir="src/" destdir="build/classes" debug="true" includeantruntime="true">
    <classpath>
        <path refid="classpath"/>
    </classpath>
</javac>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="src/" destdir="build/" classpathref="classpath"/>
    <mkdir dir="app"/>
    <jar destfile="app/Downloader.jar" basedir="build/classes/">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="downloader.Downloader"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${mf.classpath}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build"/>
    <delete dir="app"/>
</target>
```

and ls in my lib folder:

bundle-jars.jar 
cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar
client-combined-3.0.1-nodeps.jar
commons-codec-1.10.jar
commons-exec-1.3.jar
commons-io-2.5.jar
commons-lang3-3.4.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
cssparser-0.9.20.jar
gson-2.3.1.jar
guava-19.0.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
hamcrest-library-1.3.jar
htmlunit-core-js-2.23.jar
htmlunit-driver-2.23.jar
htmlunit-2.23.jar
httpclient-4.5.2.jar
httpcore-4.4.4.jar
httpmime-4.5.2.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
jcip-annotations-1.0.jar
jcommander-1.48.jar
jetty-io-9.2.13.v20150730.jar
jetty-util-9.2.13.v20150730.jar
jna-platform-4.1.0.jar
jna-4.1.0.jar
junit-4.12.jar
neko-htmlunit-2.23.jar
netty-3.5.7.Final.jar
phantomjsdriver-1.3.0.jar
sac-1.3.jar
selenium-api-3.0.1.jar
selenium-html-runner-3.0.1.jar
selenium-chrome-driver-3.0.1.jar
selenium-java-3.0.1.jar
selenium-remote-driver-3.0.1.jar
selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
selenium-support-3.0.1.jar
selenium-3.0.1-nodeps.jar
serializer-2.7.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar
snakeyaml-1.15.jar
websocket-api-9.2.15.v20160210.jar
websocket-client-9.2.15.v20160210.jar
websocket-common-9.2.15.v20160210.jar
xalan-2.7.2.jar
xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
zt-zip-1.8.jar

Comment: please show what you have currently in `lib directory and build.xml`

Comment: Why are you compiling your code twice (once outside of a target, and then again in the compile target)? Anyway, it looks like you need to include at least one of those Selenium libs in your jar as a runtime dependency.